# how to merge two arrays together and use json_encode

Tags: php, json

I have the following php code,

```
<?php
$first = array(1,2,3);
$last = array(4,5,6);
$k = 10;

echo json_encode(array('id' =>$k, 'name' => array( 'first' => $first, 'last' => $last)));
?>
```

I only get this result

```
{"id":10,"name":{"first":[1,2,3],"last":[4,5,6]}}
```

but I want the following format, so that I can access the data in javascript like name.first and name.last

```
{"id":10,"name":[{"first":1,"last":4},{"first":2,"last":5},{"first":3,"last":6}] }
```

can anyone help me out?

Thanks,

Pat

Comment: can you show us the desired array in php format?

Comment: The JSON output is provided. That is enough.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary we don't all haver your god like ability to understand JSON.

Comment: @Dagon then paste it in jsonlint or do a simple print_r(json_decode('{"json":["scary","not_scary"]}')); ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) to operate in the same time on the multiple arrays:

```
$array = array_map(function ($first, $last) { return array("first" => $first, "last" => $last); }, $first, $last);
echo json_encode(array('id' =>$k, 'name' => $array));
```

Comment: + was interested to see the answers here. Elegant.

Comment: Nice solution indeed. +1

Comment: I am not sure why it is not working for me, $array variable is empty after running that code

Comment: @Pat see http://3v4l.org/6tjqY … you must have done something wrong when copying?

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for a brute force solution for this:

```
$first = array(1,2,3);
$last  = array(4,5,6);
$name  = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < count($first); $i++) {
    $name[$i]['first'] = $first[$i];
    $name[$i]['last']  = $last[$i];
}
echo json_encode(array('id' =>$k, 'name' =>$name));
```

Comment: @AmalMurali this is just the mapping part. assuming all the other code as it is

Comment: thanks, it works. is this way slower than the array_map solution above?

Comment: @Pat very similar time. just array_map is _the more elegant solution_ ;-)